# how to change color of status bar of imagepickercontroller ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, ios7-statusbar

I need something like this [status bar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcmei.png) but i am getting the status hidden but still i can not change the color. I am getting this [status bar withour color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVUWa.png)

This is what i am doing.

-

```
(void)showGallery
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
//    picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
//    picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
    picker.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
    picker.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    picker.navigationBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlack;
   [ picker.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use three steps:

1: Add `UINavigationControllerDelegate`, `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` to your `@interface yourController ()<>`

2:

```
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
```

3:

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Try This:-`**

1.Create a view with height 20 points and change the background color to attach the viewcontrollerView (OR) change the background colour of your view controller follow like

```
UIView*statusbarview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 20)];
statusbarview.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.view addSubview:statusbarview];
```

(OR)

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This solved my problem.

-(void)showGallery
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    picker.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    picker.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    picker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    picker.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:  [UIColor whiteColor]};
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```